# No le puedo poner imagen de fondo a mi formulario.. en visual studio

Tags: c#

Este es el código para que asigne fondo en el diseñador:

```
internal static Bitmap email_bg
{
    get
    {
        return (Bitmap)RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(AutoOffers.My.Resources.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("email_bg", AutoOffers.Resources.resourceCulture));
    }
}
```

Ya que de no ser así solo puedo ponerle fondo de color xd.

Me sale el siguiente error:

> 'Resources.resourceCulture' no es accesible debido a su nivel de protección

Necesito ponerle algo en el bitmap ya que de no ser así el valor es nulo entonces no me muestra el fondo..

Una captura por si acaso[image: ok]

Comment: Prueba a `public` en vez de `internal`, talvez te ayude. Si no es muy importante el nivel de accesibilidad.

Comment: lo arregle creando un formulario nuevo y luego métiendo el código. Importe de manera local al formulario la foto o imagen de fondo. Gracias por su continua ayuda resulta muy útil dios le bendiga.. a todos..

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar utilizando la propiedad BackgroundImage del formulario en la ventana Propiedades. Haga clic en el botón de puntos suspensivos para abrir el cuadro de diálogo Seleccionar recurso y lo agrega al fondo de tu WinForm

Te dejo un tutorial que detalla como hacerlo
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dff9f95f(v=vs.110).aspx

Saludos!!

Comment: Si va a poner un link, porfavor que este sea solo para futuras referencias, ¿Puede explicar un poco sobre como utilizar la propiedad, para que si en dado momento el link deja de funcionar, la respuesta aún tenga validez?

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes hacer algo como:

```
private string ruta = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"ImagenesForm\Moda.png");
private void frmMDI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(ruta);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
    }
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.